# Dynamic form with wysiwyg issues

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I'm having issues with dynamic form with wysiwyg editor. I'm using FCKEditor (I'm forced to).

From the begining, I create a cute form in Fencybox, working correctly. I'm having only one small isssue, form is not sending any value. According to documentation [link text](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP) everything is implemented correctly.

I'm trying to get editor content by:

```
var comment = $("#comment").val();
```

Not working, wondering why. Do you have any suggestions?

**Edit**
alert(comment); return nothing. But when I put in:

```
success: function(html){
    alert(comment);
}
```

it works correctly. Any ideas?

Regards,
Tom

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic form. Is the form inside the WYSIWYG HTML? Or outside? Can you show some finished HTML code?

Comment: I meant AJAX form. Here's HTML output...
 <form name="comment" id="comment" method="post">       
 <input type="hidden" id="comment_body" name="comment_body" value="" style="display:none" /><input type="hidden" id="comment_body___Config" value="" style="display:none" /><iframe id="comment_body___Frame" src="/js/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=comment_body&amp;Toolbar=Profile" width="473" height="230" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: What code are you using to initialize the FCKEditor inside the AJAX Form?

Comment: Identical to the code from documentation. It must be everything with jQuery selector, but have do idea what. Noticed strange thing, edited post.

Comment: Identical code from which documentation?

Comment: Of course, FCKEditor. Issues are solved now, thanks **Pekka** for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CKEditor JavaScript API to retrieve the HTML value:

```
var comment = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('comment_body').GetHTML();
```

Comment: +1 - Yeah I was sure there was a better way with the API, I just couldn't find it :P

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want... the jQuery selector you have there won't return anything because you are trying to get the value of the form (`#comment` is the id of your form)

The editor content is actually inside of an iframe or textarea depending if you are looking at the source... try this:

```
var content = ($('textarea.cke_source').length) ? $('textarea.cke_source').val() : $('table.cke_editor iframe').contents().find('body').html();
```

Edit: Use Jon's answer... now that I look again, I think this was for CKEditor and not FCKEditor, it's easy to confuse the two.